# Batch mv or rename in bash script - append date as a suffix

Tags: bash

After much searching and trial and error, I'm unable to do a batch `mv` or `rename` on a directory of files.  What I'd like to do is move or rename all files in a directory so that the `mv`'d or `rename`d file has `$date (+ '%Y%d%m')` added to the original suffix.

All the original files have unique prefixes but are either `.xml` or `.txt` so I'd like to go from `org_prefix.org_suffix` -> `org_prefix.org_suffix.DATE`

I've tried this:

```
$ mv /directory/* /directory/*$(date (+ '%Y%m%d')
```

but always get `/directory/*.actualdate' is not a directory` error.

I've tried this:

```
$ for f in *; do mv $ $f.$(date +'_%m%d%y'); done
```

but I get `mv: cannot stat '$'; No such file or directory`

Lastly, I've even tried this:

```
$ rename 's/*/.test/' *
```

just to see if I could change all the files to `org_prefix.test` but nothing happens (no errors, nada, zip)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to loop through files (and e.g., print their name) in the current directory is:

```
for file in *; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

How will you append the date? like so, of course:

```
for file in *; do
    echo "$file.$(date +%Y%m%d)"
done
```

And how are you going to do the move? like so, of course:

```
for file in *; do
    mv -nv -- "$file" "$file.$(date +%Y%m%d)"
done
```

I've added:

- `-v` so that `mv` be verbose (I like to know what's happening and it always impresses my little sister to watch all these lines flowing on the screen).
- `-n` so as to no overwrite an otherwise existing file. Safety first.
- `--` just in case a file name starts with a hyphen: without `--`, `mv` would confuse with an option. Safety first.

If you just want to look through the files with extension `.banana`, replace the `for` with:

```
for file in *.banana; do
```

of for files that contain the word `banana`:

```
for file in *banana*; do
```

and so on.

Keep up with the bananas!

Comment: Thank for this - it works as well. If I wanted to put this in bash script and have this called from a cron job, would the proper syntax be:

for file in /some_directory/*; do
    mv -nv -- "$file" "/new_directory$file$(date +%Y%m%d)"
done

Comment: @user2755742 if it's called from a cronjob, you don't need the `-v` switch, unless you want to log this output. Apart from this it's all good! (try the script before putting it in the crontable, to check that everything is okay).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mv /directory/* /directory/*$(date (+ '%Y%m%d')
```

This does not work, because the `*` is expanded to a list of all files, so after the expansion the command will be something like:

```
mv /directory/file1 /directory/file2 /directory/file3 /directory/file1_date /directory/file1_date ...
```

So you have specified many destinations, but the syntax for mv allows only one single destination.

```
for f in *; do mv $ $f.$(date +'_%m%d%y'); done
```

Here you forgot the `f` after the `$`, that's why you get the error message.

```
for f in *; do mv $f $f.$(date +'%m%d%y'); done
```

I think this should work now, but don't forget to quote all the variables!

Finally:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.$(date +'%m%d%y')"; done
```

Edit: When there are characters directly after a variable, it's good practice to use `{}` to make clear that they are not part of the variable name:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f}.$(date +'%m%d%y')"; done
```